# Controlling the spectrum of $S + \mu \vec{v} \vec{v}^\dagger$ by changing $\mu$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, symmetric-matrices

Suppose we have a hermitian matrix $S \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$. For $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{v} \in {\mathbb{C}^N}$ , let
$$ \tag{1} S(\mu) = S + \mu \cdot \vec{v} \vec{v}^{\dagger}.$$

The claim is that for any $s \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $\mu$ such that the following eigenvalue equation is true:
$$ \tag{2} S(\mu) \vec{u} = s \vec{u}.$$

Specifically, $\mu(s)$ is given as follows:
$$\tag{3} \mu(s) = \left( \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\langle\vec{s}_n, \vec{v} \rangle^2}{s-s_n} \right)^{-1}.$$
In the above, $\vec{s}_n$ and $s_n$ are eigenvectors and non-degenerate eigenvalues of $S$.
**How do I derive Eq (3) ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that if $s = s_n$ for any $n$, we can just take $\mu = 0$, so we only need to do the $s \neq s_n$ case.

Since $S$ is Hermitian, we let $S = U \Lambda U^*$ be its eigendecomposition, with $U$ unitary having columns $\{\mathbf{s}_n\}$.
Now, we need to solve the equation
\begin{align*}
0
= \det(S + \mu vv^* - sI)
= \det(\Lambda - sI + \mu (U^* v) (U^*v)^*).
\end{align*}

For clearer notation, we'll write $\tilde{v} := U^*v$, and factor out the diadonal $\Lambda - sI$ to get
\begin{align*}
0
&= \det(\Lambda - sI) \det (I + (\Lambda - sI)^{-1} \mu \tilde{v} \tilde{v}^*).
\end{align*}

Since $s \neq s_n$ for all $n$, we have that $\det(\Lambda - sI) \neq 0$, so we only need to solve the latter term being zero.
Moreover, determinants have the important property that $\det(I + AB) = \det(I + BA)$ for any matrices $A, B$, such that $AB$ and $BA$ are both square (this comes from the fact that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues, except if one of then has more rows and columns, it has enough additional eigenvalues with value 0 to make up this difference).

So we have now reduced the problem to solving
\begin{align*}
0
&= \det(I + \mu \cdot \tilde{v}^* (\Lambda - sI)^{-1} \tilde{v}) \\
&= 1 + \mu \cdot \tilde{v}^* (\Lambda - sI)^{-1} \tilde{v} \\
&= 1 + \mu \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{|\tilde{v}_n|^2}{s_n - s}, \\
\mu
&= \Bigl(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{|\tilde{v}_n|^2}{s - s_n}\Bigr)^{-1}.
\end{align*}

But recall that $\tilde{v} = U^* v$, so that $\tilde{v}_n = \langle \mathbf{s}_n, v\rangle$, which yields
$$
\mu
= \Bigl(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{|\langle \mathbf{s}_n, v\rangle|^2}{s - s_n}\Bigr)^{-1}.
$$

I realise that this has an extra square exponent when compared to your eq. (3), but I believe that this is the correct expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a clear derivation! This was more complicated than I expected. Damian, one question, though. What is the motivation or higher level thinking behind of trying to solve $\det(S + \mu v v^* - sI)=0$? Is it for getting a characteristic polynomial and then solving for $\mu$ instead of $s$ as it is usually done for finding eigenvalues? Where does this formula arise?

Comment: Exactly! We;re used to situations where the matrix is fixed and we're solving for the eigenvalue - here, it's the eigenvalue that's fixed and we're solving for (a parameter of) the matrix. So $P_{\mu}(s) = \det(S + \mu vv^* - sI)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $S(\mu)$. Then, for a fixed $s$, we're solving the equation $P_\mu(s) = 0$ for $\mu$ to ensure that $s$ is an eigenvalue of $S(\mu)$.

Comment: Also, made a few corrections - I'm used to dealing with real symmetric matrices, so I got sloppy with complex numbers!